# Calculate y position from hypotenuse

Tags: geometry, triangles

Context: I am building a design tool.
Video of the problem: https://share.getcloudapp.com/z8uYpKv2

I have a rectangle that can be resized proportionally (scaled) as you can see in the video. Inside the rectangle, I have child rectangles that need to adjust based on the parent rectangle.

Here is how I am calculating the changes as the box moves for the width, height, and x coordinates. I am having trouble with the y-axis.

Let's start the box dimensions at 100x100 with a child box at 50x50, then it scales down to 50x50 (0.5). The child then becomes 25x25.

[image]

**Calculations**

width = 50 / 100 * 25 **(new width / original width * original box width)**

height = 50 / 100 * 25 **(new height / original height * original box height)**

x = 0 - (-50) **(original x - delta x)**

y = ??

Here is what I am trying to achieve https://share.getcloudapp.com/Z4uyeWbO. You can see the parent square is being scaled down, and the child is moving in accordance with the parent. The width is shrinking at scale, the height is shrinking at scale, also the X position is moving from a delta. The hard part to solve is the Y position, it appears to be moving along the hypotenuse. This is what I am trying to solve for -- I am not sure how to put this in math terms.

Here is what I have tried.

y = 50 / 100 / √2 * 50 **(new height / original height / square root(2) * original y)**

Sorry if the way I communicated this is weird, I am not very math-oriented and excited to learn here, so I appreciate your understanding and patience.

Comment: Looks like you want to have the whole diagram shrink down to the upper right-hand corner of the original square, right?

Comment: Yeah, not just the upper left hand though. The box can be reszied in any direction. The idea is as the box is resizing the children's Y position will need to move accordingly. This is because it has to be managed with CSS. I am having a hard time finding the proper rate at which it needs to move up or down. I figured by calculating the change in the hypotenuse I would be able to figure the rate at which it needs to move on the Y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best performed by using linear transformations on a coordinate system, where the origin is placed at the vertex of the scaling box that does not move.  In other words, if you "grab" the vertex in the lower left, the origin will be the vertex that remains stationary--the one in the upper right.  You calculate all of the coordinates of the vertices relative to that origin, and then the scaling transformation would be of the form $(x, y) \mapsto (cx, cy)$ for some scaling constant $c$ that depends on the location of the mouse pointer.

For instance, the coordinates of the large box would be in counterclockwise order $(0,0)$, $(-100,0)$, $(-100,-100)$, $(0,-100)$.  Let us assume that prior to the scaling the smaller box's coordinates are $$\{(-40,-50), (-90,-50), (-90,-100), (-40,-100)\}.$$

Then if you choose a scaling factor $c$ based on how the corner at $(-100,-100)$ is moved, e.g., $c = 1/2$, the new coordinates of the outer box become $$\{(0,0), (-50,0), (-50,-50), (0,-50)\}.$$  The inner box becomes $$\{(-20, -25), (-45, -25), (-45,-50), (-20,-50)\}.$$  This furnishes a computationally simple way to rescale.

The only remaining part is to figure out how to recalculate the coordinates based on the choice of vertex to move.  If you had moved instead the lower right vertex, the origin would need to be located at the upper left, and the outer box would be $$\{(100,0), (0,0), (0,-100), (100,-100)\}$$ with the inner box coordinates modified accordingly.  This is not difficult to do; if in general your scaling box has vertices at $$\{(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3), (x_4, y_4)\},$$ where there are restrictions on the $x_i$ and $y_i$ such that these points define a rectangular region with sides parallel to the coordinate axes, then a simple translation can remap all the coordinates based on any choice of vertex; e.g., if I wanted to make the point $(x_2, y_2)$ the origin, I simply subtract $(x_2, y_2)$ from all of the vertices in this list:
$$\{(x_1 - x_2, y_1 - y_2), (0,0), (x_3-x_2, y_3-y_2), (x_4-x_2, y_4-y_2)\}.$$

Comment: This looks great. I have a lot to research here but excited to dive deep into it. I'll try and plug this into the program and will report back shortly.

Comment: "for some scaling constant  that depends on the location of the mouse pointer." Instead of the location of the mouse pointer, wouldn't it be easier to use a delta?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry however you want.  It depends on what you are trying to do.  If you want the scaling to respond to mouse movement, then you’d need to use that information to calculate $c$.  If you don’t, you can just pick any value you want.

Comment: Ive been working on this for a while. I understand it like 75%, the problem I am facing is the fact I am manipulating CSS so it's a slightly different way of thinking about it. I know this is the correct answer so I will mark it. In order to solve my problem maybe it's best to ask it on Stack Overflow? I created a CodeSandbox for those to tinker around. I am not sure if you know JavaScript, but I will share anyways -- here is a video https://share.getcloudapp.com/qGuv1zLk and here is the code you can mess with https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-https-ll95b?file=/src/Resizer.tsx:1208-1214

Comment: Ok I solved it. I didn't follow this exact formula because in the code I was able to calculate the needed coordinates based on a scale factor and monitoring the parent dimensions. https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-https-ll95b?file=/src/Resizer.tsx